# Correct comma placement in a sentence containing 'for instance'

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

In short, which sentence seems to be more correct? This:

> It can be done, for instance by mixing in following ingredients.

or maybe this one:

> It can be done for instance, by mixing in following ingredients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BobRodes' answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131140/correct-comma-placement-in-a-sentence-containing-for-instance#131158) is correct that the best usage here is to have both commas. But it's also possible to omit one; in this case, you can omit the second one, in order to have a faster flow and tighter connection between the interrupting element that introduces the clause and the contents of it. This tends to work better with very short interjections, for example this one.

You can't omit the first comma, though, because that breaks the sentence in the wrong place, leading to confusion: "It can be done" is *not* the "instance" you're talking about!

Comment: While I don't fully disagree with this, it should be mentioned that the AP Style manual, the Chicago Manual of Style, the US Government Printing Office Style Manual and the Oxford Guide to English Grammar all state that both commas are to be used in this case.  But "...very short interjections, for example, this one." certainly looks quite stuffy, and the examples they use are generally longer.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, "for instance" is an *interrupting element*.  As such, it should be entirely set off by commas, so:

> It can be done, for instance, by mixing in the following ingredients.

If you google "punctuation rules commas" you will find quite a few guides on the use of commas and other punctuation.  [This one](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html) is a good place to start.